# Separable Differential Equation (Check Answer)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question:** Determine all differentiable functions in the form $y$ = $f(x)$ which have the properties:
>
> $f'(x)$=$(f(x))^3$ and $f(0)=2$

---

What I have done

I set up the differential equation as such

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = y^3 $$

$$ \int y^{-3} dy = \int dx$$

$$ {-1\over 2y^2} = x + c $$

$$ {1\over 2y^2} = -x-c $$

At $y = 2 , x = 0 , c = -\frac{1}{8}$

$$ {1\over 2y^2} = {1\over 8} - x$$

$$ 2y^2 = {8\over {1-8x}} $$

$$ y^2  = {4\over {1-8x}} $$

$$ y = ±\sqrt{4\over {1-8x}} $$

Is this correct? Are there any limits of x or y to consider?

Comment: Yes it is okay.

Comment: But if the sign is negative then is your initial condition true?

Comment: @ElliotG Therefore the conditions is y = the positive equation not negative and x =/= 1/8?

Comment: @dydxx That is correct